# Facing issue in display:inline-block property

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two divs side by side using css `display: inline-block;` property. But my divs are placed one below the other.

Link of fiddle:-
https://jsfiddle.net/04cc1n8j/

HTML

```
<div class='outerDiv'>
  <div class='innerDiv1'></div>
  <div class='innerDiv2'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outerDiv{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.innerDiv1{
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.innerDiv2{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:green;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/04cc1n8j/4/)

Comment: Several solutions to this. Here's one: remove whitespace in HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/04cc1n8j/5/ ... see dupe for other methods and explanations.

Comment: Try floating them instead, then declare `overflow: auto` on the parent element to clear the `float`. Or apply `margin-right: -4px;` to `.innerDiv1`.

Comment: Thanks Michael_B & chipChocolate.py for helping with the correct answers

Answer (score 1):

The width of the white-space between the `inline-block` elements is breaking your layout. [This article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) should help.

Comment: Thanks Ito, this article was really helpful.